# How to start x with zsh?

Tags: zsh, startx

I want `zsh` to start x automatically on the first login.

After I added

```
if systemctl -q is-active graphical.target && [[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]]; then
  exec startx
fi
```

to the file `~/.zprofile`. however I need to login twice until xinit starts i3.

BTW I use Arch

my `.xinitrc` looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
# exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
xrandr --output DP-3 --same-as LVDS-1 
exec i3
```

Comment: I don't know what you have, But if you have kali, you can use `startx`, and with other distros, you can start gdm or kdm.

Comment: So do you mean I can just omit the if block. BTW I use arch

Comment: You only need start `gdm3` service via `service gdm3 start`

Comment: Please explain your requirements in the question. On your system X should not be started until a user logs in who happens to use `zsh`? Do you want to run a display manager that requires a graphical login or do you want to directly associate the X server with the user who started it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Do you want a login prompt in text mode or graphical mode? If you have a text mode prompt, `systemctl -q is-active graphical.target` would be false.

Answer (score 2):

Very late response, but just stumbled upon the same problem and wanted to give a quick solution for my use case, which I suspect is the same as the OP's. Just to clarify though, this is for starting Xorg right after having logged in using "text mode". So no display managers like gdm or lightdm.

All you need to is to add these lines to the end of your `.zshrc` :

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then 
  exec startx &>/dev/null 
fi
```

Essentially, all this does is run Xorg (without all the annoying output...) if it isn't started yet and if you're on tty1. The latter is just in case Xorg fails on startup and you need to change some configuration files (very useful in my opinion....).

Hope this helps.

*Note: you can use the same code in bash.*

Answer (score 1):

I reformulate slightly, hopefully keeping the Q's spirit:

How to start X by a shell command? How to do it at system startup?

I ignore your systemctl and much of your .xinitrc.

The most basic user command is `xinit`. It is hard to say what it does, exactly. It has a special semantic and syntax. To answer the Q:

`xinit fvwm` does start x server.

It defaults to `xinit fvwm -- X :0` which means as much as:

Initialize X SERVER "X" on DISPLAY "0" with window MANAGER `fvwm`

It has to be so complicated, because it is powerful. X server and a window manager turn a TTY into a so-called DISPLAY.

If you go only `xinit`, you get that special xclock-only environment. (without any "hidden" defaults, of course. See man xinit. Also man startx. Compare!).

Of course you need `xorg.conf` configured! (gpu card, input devices for x)

Of course you need a window manager`, (minimally) configured! (fvwm, twm, ...)

To start X via `xinit` automatically, it takes some of planning and negotiating with `systemd` and your distro. Out of scope, but only for now.

"start x on the first login" needs (much) more precision; if it means have `x` running on `tty1` I can understand what it means, at least. I don't see much connection with a certain shell like `zsh`.